# jQuery Syntax error, unrecognized expression in use element id

Tags: jquery

i'm using `tShamsi__[2]` and `#tShamsi__[3]` id for elements and i can split those for can be use any action for example i canu use persian calendar for get arabic date and convert to gregorian.

**JQUERY**

```
$('[id^="tShamsi_"]').datepicker({

    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    regional: 'fa',
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
              miladi_ID = $(this).attr('id').split(/\[|\]/)[1];
              var date = new JalaliDate(inst['selectedYear'], inst['selectedMonth'], inst['selectedDay']).getGregorianDate();
              var month= (date.getMonth()+1).toString();
              if (month.length <2) month='0'+ month;

              var day= date.getDate().toString(); 
              if (day.length <2) day ='0'+ day;
              $('#miladi'+miladi_ID).val(date.getFullYear() + '-' + month + '-' + day);
            }
});
    $('#radio_content_4').change(function(){ // DISABLE INPUTS
        $('#tShamsi__[2]"]').prop('disabled', false);
    });
```

HTML:

```
 <input style='width: 100px;' class='en' id='tShamsi__[2]'  readonly='readonly' value='{$shamsi_date}' disabled='disabled'/>
 <input  type='hidden' id='miladi2'>
```

my problem: i can use datePicker and split,convert that but for disable inputs i get this error,`Syntax error, unrecognized expression`

Comment: Why the quotes in '#tShamsi__[2]"]' ?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery syntax, just like the one of css selectors isn't able to select with a # any element having a valid id.

You can use

```
$('[id="tShamsi__[2]"]')
```

or

```
$(document.getElementById('tShamsi__[2]')
```

As you just want to enable the element, the problematic line could be shortened into

```
document.getElementById('tShamsi__[2]').disabled = false;
```

Comment: Or, you can escape the special charaters with two \